# Getting 'No-Access-Control-Origin header' is present on the requested resource CORS error in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am getting this error when attempting to call this function from my client.

Access to fetch at '{mycloudfunctionsLink}' from origin 'https://dev.{mydomain}.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

POST https://{mycloudfunctionsLink}::ERR_FAILED

```
import {logger} from "firebase-functions";
import {HttpsError, onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
initializeApp();



exports.getStripeAccountLink = onCall({secrets: ["STRIPE_SECRET"]},  async (request: any) => {

    if (!request.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new HttpsError("failed-precondition", "The function must be " +
            "called while authenticated.");
    }

    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);
    const account = stripe.accounts.create({
        type: 'express'
    })
    logger.error("STRIPE ACCOUNT: ", account.id)

    //I am not able to upload the stripe account to the firestore directly either inorder to get the account id later.
    await getFirestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(request.auth.uid)
        .set({stripe_account_id: account.id}, {merge: true});

    try {
        stripe.accountLinks.create({
            account: account.id,
            refresh_url: process.env.STRIPE_REFERSH_URL,
            return_url: process.env.STRIPE_RETURN_URL,
            type: 'account_onboarding',
        }).then((accountLink: any) => {
            return {result: accountLink.url};
        });

    } catch (error: any) {
        logger.error(error);
        throw new HttpsError("internal", error.message)
    }



})
```

Not sure what causes the CORS problem. I am dealing with an additonal problem that involes the Cloud function NOT posting to the db but that is unrelated to this question.

Comment: An `opaque response` means no returned data. You must implement CORS in your function if you return data and the client is making a `cross-origin request`. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors Adding a load balancer for your domain, with Functions as a backend, can make client requests `origin requests`. In other words, you either need to specify that cross-orgin requests from `example.com` are allowed or include your Cloud Function into the same domain name as your origin (domain name) via a load balancer or other type of proxy.